# Parameter validation, Best practices in Python

Tags: python

**Lets take an example of a API**

```
def get_abs_directory(self, path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
       return path
    else:
       return os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path))[0]
```

My question is what is the pythonic way of validating parameters, should I ignore any type of validations (I observed that all the python code does no validation at all)

1. Should I check for "path" to be empty and not null
2. Should I check the "type" of path to be string always
3. In general should I check for type of parameters ? (I guess not as python in dynamically typed)

**This question is not specific to File IO, instead FileIO is used only as an example**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned by the documentation here, Python follows an [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html?highlight=EAFP#term-eafp) approach. This means that we usually use more `try` and `catch` blocks instead of trying to validate parameters. Let me demonstrate:

```
import os


def get_abs_directory(path):
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            return path
        else:
            return os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path))[0]
    except TypeError:
        print "You inserted the wrong type!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_abs_directory(1)  # Using an int instead of a string, which is caught by TypeError
```

You *could* however, wish to code in a LBYL (Look Before You Leap) style and this would look something like this:

```
import os


def get_abs_directory(path):

    if not isinstance(path, str):
        print "You gave us the wrong type, you big meany!"
        return None

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return path
    else:
        return os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path))[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_abs_directory(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though my question was more generic. Lets say my API simply returned square() of a number. Now the question is should I have type validation in the method?

Comment: @Bhushan No, just let it *try* to do the computation. If something fails, an exception will automatically bubble up to the caller. Unless it’s actual user input, assume that people are using your API correctly.

Comment: @Bhushan I think I answered your question when I talked about EAFP. This means that you have to _try_ something, and if it fails, you deal with it. This is the modus operandi when it comes to programming in Python. Because, if you think about it, you will not usually get wrong input, so trying to check it on every single time its called is a waste of resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it helped arriving at a conclusion.

Comment: The only problem with the EAFP approach I feel is that it can be difficult to triage when the exception is thrown, as the exception is thrown at a much later stage. And also it won't always necessarily be TypeError that it throws, thus making it difficult to catch.

Answer (score 7):

[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is the de-facto standard in Python for situations like this and at the same time, nothing impedes you from following [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) all the way if you like to.

However, there are reservations when [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is applicable:

- When the code is still able to deal with exception scenarios, break at some point or enable the caller to validate possible errors then it may be best just to follow the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) principle.
- When using [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) leads to silent errors then explicit checks/validations ([LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl)) may be best.

Regarding that, there is a Python module, [parameters-validation](https://github.com/allrod5/parameters-validation), to ease validation of function parameters when you need to:

```py
@validate_parameters
def register(
    token: strongly_typed(AuthToken),
    name: non_blank(str),
    age: non_negative(int),
    nickname: no_whitespaces(non_empty(str)),
    bio: str,
):
    # do register
```

*Disclaimer: I am the project maintainer.*

Answer (score 4):

even though already answered, this is too long for a comment, so i'll just add an another answer.

In general, type checking is done for two reasons: making sure your function actually completes, and avoiding difficult-to-debug downstream failures from bad output.

For the first problem, the answer is always appropriate - EAFP is the normal method. and you don't worry about bad inputs.

For the second... the answer depends on your normal use cases, and you DO worry about bad inputs/bugs. EAFP is still appropriate (and it's easier, and more debuggable) when bad inputs always generate exceptions (where 'bad inputs' can be limited to the types of bad inputs that your app expects to produce, possibly). But if there's a possibility bad inputs could create a valid output, then LYBL may make your life easier later.

Example: let's say that you call square(), put this value into a dictionary, and then (much) later extract this value from the dictionary and use it as an index. Indexes, of course, must be integers.

square(2) == 4, and is a valid integer, and so is correct. square('a') will always fail, because 'a'*'a' is invalid, and will always throw an exception. If these are the only two possibilities, then you can safely use EAFP. if you do get bad data, it will throw an exception, generate a traceback, and you can restart with pdb and get a good indication of what's wrong.

however... let's say that your app uses some FP. and it's possible (assuming you have a bug! not normal operation of course) for you to accidentally call square(1.43). This will return a valid value - 2.0449 or so. you will NOT get exception here, and so your app will happily take that 2.0449 and put it in the dictionary for you. Much later, your app will pull this value back out of the dictionary, use it as an index into a list and - crash. You'll get a traceback, you'll restart with pdb, and realize that doesn't help you at all, because that value was calculated a long time ago, and you no longer have the inputs, or any idea how that data got there. And those are not fun to debug.

In those cases, you can use asserts (special form of LYBL) to move detection of those sorts of bugs earlier, or you can do it explicitly. If you don't ever have a bug calling that function, then either one will work. But if you do... then you'll really be glad you checked the inputs artificially close to the failure, rather than naturally some random later place in your app.

Answer (score 1):

The code does "trap" errors as this test code shows, an exception is raised for passing in None

```
import os.path
import os


class pathetic(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        if (not(os.path.exists("ABC"))):
            os.mkdir("ABC")
        else:
            self.assert_(False, "ABC exists, can't make test fixture")

    def tearDown(self):
        if (os.path.exists("ABC")):
            os.rmdir("ABC")

    def test1(self):
        mycwd = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))[0]
        self.assertEquals("/", self.get_abs_directory("/abc"))
        self.assertEquals(mycwd, self.get_abs_directory(""))
        self.assertEquals("/ABC", self.get_abs_directory("/ABC/DEF"))
        try:
            self.get_abs_directory(None)
            self.assert_(False, "should raise exception")
        except TypeError:
            self.assert_(True, "woo hoo, exception")

    def get_abs_directory(self, path):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            return path
        else:
            return os.path.split(os.path.abspath(path))[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Please see my reply to Brainiac, I am looking for some guidelines wrt to Pythonic way of handling method parameters.